# How to iterate through every directory?

Tags: ruby

I have a directory structure such as:

```
-A
  --a
  .txt
-B
  --b
-C
  --c
  .txt
```

I need to check every folder `A,B,C` for `.txt` file and if it's in run some method. I tried to do it through `Find.find` but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the directories from current directory

```
Dir["./**/*.txt"]
```

Exactly those three directories from current directory

```
%w(A B C).flat_map { |dir| Dir["./#{dir}/**/*.txt"] }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And if there are one hundred folders how to replace %w(A B C)?

Comment: Try this way `Dir["*"].select { |filename| File.directory?(filename) } - %w(dir1 dir2)`

Comment: In that way you can exclude some directories of your choice